# How to prove: $-1\le x\le 1\implies 0\le \sqrt{1-x^2} \le 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that: $$-1\le x\le 1\implies 0\le \sqrt{1-x^2} \le 1.$$

So, I read this part in an answer somewhere and thought it'd be quite easy but I can't seem to get how to prove that $-1\le x\le 1$ implies $0\le \sqrt{1-x^2} \le1$.

What I did as the first step is:
$$-1\le x\le 1 \implies 1\le x^2\le 1$$
i.e. I squared the inequality.

Now I can see that I won't be able to get a solution now. So that may mean I can't just square an inequality like this, but I don't remember reading any rules regarding that.

And *if* there is a rule regarding squaring, then what about raising it to 3rd or 4th power?

Comment: Well squaring can only ever give you a positive number or $0$. That is the case for all even exponents, but not all odd exponents.

Comment: @Harry, does that mean my first step is wrong? And then what can I do?

Comment: It must be less than/equal to 1 and greater than/equal to 0

Comment: @Harry, ok, I get this on an intuitive level. But I don't remember reading any rule regarding this and the first step I followed seems to obey the rules of  mathematical operations on inequalities, or does it break some rule?

Comment: In the case of $x$ being greater than/equal to $-1$, when you square $x$, you are multiplying by a negative number which means you have to reverse the inequality sign.  That is a fundamental rule of mathematical operations on inequalities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$-1\le x\le1$$
$$-1\le x<0\lor0\le x\le1$$
$$1\ge x^2>0\lor0\le x^2\le1$$
$$0\le x^2\le1$$
$$0\le1-x^2\le1$$
$$0\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\le1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now, I don't know what∨means.

Comment: @MrReality Logical OR. $a\lor b$ = either $a$ true or $b$ true (or both).

Comment: Ok, I get the steps mentioned but this mean if I have an inequality $x \ge -1$ then I can't square both sides to write it $x^2 \ge 1$?

Comment: @MrReality When raising both sides to even powers, you have to break the inequality into two parts at 0, then square both parts normally, then combine them. With $x\ge-1$ you would get $x\ge0$ and $0>x\ge-1$, squaring to $x^2\ge0$ and $x^2>0$, combining to $x^2\ge0$.

Comment: Squaring the "normal" way, for the second expression, aren't we getting $0> x^2 \ge -1$?

Comment: @MrReality No, no, trite! Squares of real numbers are always positive!

Comment: Sorry, I meant $0> x^2 \ge 1$, aren't we getting this?

Comment: @MrReality _A bit better_ but the inequality signs are reversed in that last equation.

Comment: Why so? (I've read that inequality signs are only reversed if we are multiplying by a negative number or taking the reciprocal of the numbers (in the inequality).

Comment: @MrReality Effectively we are multiplying $0>x\ge-1$ by $x$ here. Now $x$ is negative. So the inequality signs are reversed.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. *Thanks so much for your help*!!

Comment: @MrReality Please accept my answer.

Comment: I think I'll wait for a day or two to see if there are more answers. Then I'll decide.

Comment: Accepted (Finally?)!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b>0$,

if $\ -a < x < b$, then $\ 0 \leq x^2 < \max\{a^2,b^2\}$

In general,

If $\ -a<x<b$, and $n$ is an even number, $0 \leq x^n < \max\{a^n,b^n\}$.

If, otherwise, $-a<x<b$ and $n$ is odd, then $-a^n < x^n <b^n$

Comment: I didn't understand this at first but now I do. Thanks, this is instructive for me.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in\Bbb R$ we know $x^2\geq 0$. Hence,
$$-1\leq x\leq 1\implies 0\leq x^2\leq 1\implies -1\leq -x^2\leq 0\implies 0\leq 1-x^2\leq 1$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Now, if the square of -1 & 1 are the same (i.e. 1), then how can we get two different numbers (0 & 1) in your second step?

Comment: @MrReality if you square any number $x$ such that $|x|\leq 1$ you get a number $x^2$ such that $|x^2|\leq 1$. But, $|x^2|=x^2$. Hence, $0\leq x^2\leq 1$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that but at the same time, I did follow the rules of mathematical operations on inequalities in my first step, right? Or did I break some rule?

Comment: You're first step is wrong, although I see why you did it. However, if you think about $1\leq x^2\leq 1$ we'd have to have $x^2=1$, which is certainly not true for any $-1\leq x\leq 1$. The rule you broke is that you can say $a\leq b\implies a^2\leq b^2$ if both $a,b$ are nonnegative.

Comment: And trivially, if both are negative then too, right?

Comment: No. Take $a=-3, b=-2$ then $-3\leq -2$, yet $(-3)^2=9\not\leq 4=(-2)^2$.

Comment: "However, if you think about $1\le x^2\le1$ we'd have to have $x^2=1$..." - I don't understand this part.

Comment: If $1\leq x^2$ and $x^2\leq 1$ we'd have to have $x^2=1$.

Comment: Ok, understood this part, thanks Dave!!

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that $$0\leq1-x^2\leq1$$ or
$$-1\leq-x^2\leq0$$ or
$$1\geq x^2\geq0$$ or
$$|x|\leq1$$ or
$$-1\leq x\leq1,$$
which is given.

Done!

Comment: Actually, we need to prove $ 0\le \sqrt{1- x^2} \le 1$?

Comment: @Mr Reality Yes of course! For which we need to prove that $0\leq1-x^2\leq1$... See better my solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see this now. *Thanks for answering and editing the question*!

Comment: @Mr Reality You are welcome! Good luck!